# differential equations $dX(t)/dt = f(X(t),t)+\int_{0}^t dW_s$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

I have an equation like $dX(t)/dt = f(X(t),t)+\int_{0}^t dW_s$. I was wondering if there is a way to solve it (even in the simple case like $f(X(t),t) = g(X(t))h(t)$). Any hint will be much appreciated!

EDIT: I found this paper [Second order stochastic differential equations with Dirichlet boundary conditions](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030441499190028B). But I would like to have a Cauchy boundary condition

Comment: Can you verifying that the LHS is $dX/dt$ and first term on RHS doesn't read $f(X(t), t)dt$?

Comment: For example the solution to $dX_t=X_t dt+ W_t dt$ is also interesting for you?

Comment: @PontusHultkrantz Yes I can verify that. Thank you!

Comment: @Math-fun Yes, that would give me some hints. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\frac{dX_t}{dt} &= f(X_t,t) + \int_0^tdW_s \\
&:= f(X_t,t) + dW_t \\
&\Longleftrightarrow \\
dX_t &= f(X_t,t)dt + dW_tdt.
\end{align}
Now since $dW_tdt = 0$ we have that the stochastic part vanishes, so

\begin{align}
dX_t &= f(X_t,t)dt \\
&\Longleftrightarrow \\
\frac{dX_t}{dt} &- f(X_t,t) = 0, \\
\end{align}
which is a differential equation of first order. The solution depends on the form of $f$

If $f$ is separable as $f(X_t,t)=g(X_t)h(t)$, that leads to
\begin{align}
 \frac{1}{g(X)}dX_t = h(t)dt,
\end{align}
which can be solved following [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables).

Comment: Thank you! If I am not mistaken, $\int_0^t dW_s = W_t$ rather than $dW_t$?

Comment: So when writing $dW_t$ in a stochastic equation, it is an abbreviation for $\int_0^t dW_s = W_t-W_0$. Similarly, $dX_t$ is short for $\int_0^t dX_s = X_t-X_0$. Another typical example is $\sigma(t)dW_t$ which is short for $\int_0^t \sigma(s)dW_s$.

Comment: Thank you! But this is very unintuitive. The rate of X(t) depends on a random variable, and how can X(t) be deterministic? Would you mind explaining more? Thank you very much!

Comment: @huighlh It is more intuitive to write the differentials as finites differences. Assume $f(X_t,t) = \mu$, such that $dX_t/dt = \mu + dW_t$. Write in finite form with $t_i = i\tfrac{T}{n}$ and $\Delta t =T/n$, and denote $X_i := X(t_i)$. Then the equation is $\frac{X_{i+1}-X_i}{\Delta t} =\mu + W_{i+1}-W_i$, which is a recursion $X_{i+1} = X_i + \mu \Delta t + (W_{i+1}-W_i)\Delta t  = X_0 + (i+1)\mu \Delta t + (W_{i+1}-W_0)\Delta t$. We can write $X(T) = X(t_n) = X_0 + n\mu \Delta t + (W_T-W_0)\Delta t$. When $\Delta t \to 0$, the last term goes to zero, and $X_T = X_0 + \mu T$.